# Global hook in Ember when template is rendered

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to trap a global event in Ember when a template is rendered?

This is so I can invoke initialisation scripts on a per template basis as described. This isn't a candidate for initializers - I'm trying to initialise some jQuery plugins on approx 30% of pages in my application, so doing this once and not repeating myself would be great.

Failing a global hook, what is the most appropriate location to hook a template being rendered? I'm only using templates so I can't trap `didInsertElement` on a View.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's the proper way but i gave it a try as your question interested me. The follow seems to work :  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pujiqipafe/1/edit?html,js,output

Basically i use the route hook `renderTemplate`and add :

`Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', myfunction);`

after calling the `this.render()`.

You can extend this by making a

```
App.MyJqueryRoute = Ember.Route.Extend({
  renderTemplate: function(){
    this.render();
    var myjquery = function(){
      //do your jQuery stuff here
    };
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', myjquery);
  }
});
```

Then simply extend `App.MyJqueryRoute`instead of `Ember.Route.Extend` in the routes you need this functionality.

(This is a proposal idea i had while reading your post, i'm not an ember expert so i would be happy to hear any other solutions or improvement of my solutions  from the community)

Comment: Why not just reopen the Route class and override renderTemplate? It will work with all the routes. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/miluhecupi/1/edit

Comment: @blessenm cause he said on 30% of his pages, so with a reopen it would execute useless code on 70% of the pages.

Comment: Ah I didn't read the question thoroughly. Yes ur point is valid. Ur answer seems to be the way to go.

Comment: @blessenm i hope so but it would be great to have an answer from the author

Comment: Another way which I think is proper is to wrap the jquery plugins in a component and initialize them in the didInsertElement hook. This will also allow us to use the component lifecycle to do the cleanup of the plugin.